# How to reduce the size of subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have tried multiple links. I tried BARD,ChatGPT but none worked.
My problem is simple, i have to reduce the size of subplot.
I have an histogram which i want to save as pdf. i want to keep the page size as (8,3). The subplot should fit inside it. But whatever i do, i am not able to. I tried setting up the grid, reducing the size of graph but nothing is working.

```
with PdfPages(path+"\\"+Category+"_"+today+".pdf") as export_pdf:
   plt.figure(figsize=(8, 3))
   gs  = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 1, height_ratios=[1])
   ax0 = plt.subplot(gs[0])
   ax0.hist(uniqueData["Time per call"].values, edgecolor='black')
   ax0.set_xlabel('Minutes')
   ax0.set_ylabel('Frequency')
   ax0.set_title('Distribution Plot of time taken for 1 call (mins)')
   export_pdf.savefig()       
   plt.close()
```

What can i do? I want to shrink and fit histogram without changing **plt.figure(figsize=(8, 3))**

I used below code

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 3))
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.123, right=0.9, top=0.9, bottom=0.1)
plt.hist(uniqueData["Time per call"].values, edgecolor='black')
plt.xlabel('Minutes')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.title('Distribution Plot of time taken for 1 call (mins) for category: {}'.format(unique))
plt.tight_layout()
export_pdf.savefig()       
plt.close()
```

The best i could come up with is attached. I want to match boundaries of other tables in attached photo.
[image]

Comment: Do you need to be creating a multipage pdf? I.e., is using `PdfPages` necessary for your purpose? If not would the following work for you (substituting back in from above as required): `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 3)); ax.hist(...); ax.set_xlabel(...); ax.set_ylabel(...); ax.set_title(...); fig.savefig(path+"\\"+Category+"_"+today+".pdf"); plt.close()`

Comment: yes i need multipage pdf. i have to loop and save multiple graphs